# I want to check if a call instruction is part of a control flow, say if(cond) call1 else call2 how do I check that?

Tags: llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir

I want to check if a call instruction is part of a control flow, say if(cond) call1 else call2, i want to check for each callsite CallBase object, if this callsite lies in a block that is in a conditional control flow, how do I check that?

```
define i32 @foo(i1 %condition) {
  entry:
    br i1 %condition, label %true_block, label %false_block

  true_block:
    %call_true = call i32 @bar()
    br label %exit_block

  false_block:
    %call_false = call i32 @baz()
    br label %exit_block

  exit_block:
    %result = phi i32 [ %call_true, %true_block ], [ %call_false, %false_block ]
    ret i32 %result
}
```

Here bar() and baz() are conditionally reached, so yes for those two call sites, but say if the entry had a call called foo() it would not be conditional.

Is there an API that can tell me this, if not what are the algorithmic steps I need to write to check it, I suspect I would need Dominator Information as well, I appreciate any help. Thanks!

I think, I need to evaluate the predecessor block's terminator, it should be condtional branch, and there must be only one predesessor, and that predesessor must dominate all of its successors, that is if, else.if and else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *difficult* to do correctly. Allow me to outline the frustrating process of your failure (and if it sounds like I'm describing my own experience, that's because I've failed at things like this more than once):

The code you want is called [PostDominatorTree,](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PostDominatorTree.html) and it answers the question "given this block, which other blocks are definitely executed after it?" You ask that question about the entry block and have your unconditional blocks. Doing that is easy, grepping the LLVM source for `PostDominatorTree` finds some code you can <s>filch</s> learn from. But then you add another unit test:

```
a=1;
while(a)
    b();
c();
```

`b()` is reachable and somehow unconditional but how do you solve this, now? Can it be solved? Maybe. You could try to move your pass later in the pass sequence, there may be a pass that simplifies the code so you get a branch straight into the body of the loop. Or you could try to do your own [constant folding](https://llvm.org/doxygen/ConstantFolding_8h.html) in order to detect the initial truth of the condition, that may be easier depending on your source language. If this all looks very difficult, add another test:

```
while(somethingThatReturnsConstantTrue())
    a();
b();
```

`b()` definitely isn't called. And if your language uses exceptions:

```
a();
b();
```

`b()` is conditional if the first call can throw an exception.

At this point you may decide to tear all your hair out — or rewrite your problem statement to so that you're permitted to return true (or false) if you're in doubt about a call site. At this point you may be in luck, and the code you wrote using `PostDominatorTree` is all you need.

Comment: FWIW, the point about being allowed to be in doubt and return a value representing that is an important computer science theory point. Rice's Theorem states that all properties of a program which are not syntactic cannot be solved for all possible programs, due to the possibility of infinite loop. If you could prove that c() executes after b(), then you could use that function to write a Halting Problem solver, which is impossible.

Comment: Good insight. I feel, intuitively, that the main point is a different one, though: The LLVM code that "identifies most instances if […] and does […]" looks better than the code that acts on *all.* There's good-looking code that acts on all, no question. But in general, the passes with that… plain, solid, understandable, reasonable look is in passes that act on most. Code with an even distribution of complexity, without god classes or god loops.